# Overloading in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Kindly help me answering below interview question ..

Q: Why can not standalone sub-program be overloaded in oracle .only package subprogram/local subprogram can be overloaded in oracle .

Regards
Srikanta Parida

Answer (score 1):

Because stored procedure/function names are unique.
See the Oracle Documentation:

> Naming Procedures and Functions
>
> Because a procedure or function is stored in the database, it must be
>   named. This distinguishes it from other stored procedures and makes it
>   possible for applications to call it. Each publicly-visible procedure
>   or function in a schema must have a unique name, and the name must be
>   a legal PL/SQL identifier.

Answer (score 1):

A standalone procedure/function is a schema object which is identified by the combination of type and name.

You could argue that this is an arbitrary design decision. However, the benefit of overloaded functions and procedures weights small in comparison to a simpler object identifier in the data dictionary, in particular without null components all over the place.

Imho, applications that need overloaded routines should exploit the package paradigm anyway for reasons of sw engineering best practices ( like separation of concern, data encapsulation, maintainability).

NB:
Schema types offer another option to define overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is - because the documentation says that standalone subprograms cannot be overloaded:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#i12352

> **Restrictions on Overloading**
>
> Only local or packaged subprograms, or type methods, can be
>   overloaded. You cannot overload standalone subprograms.

---

Why ? You need to ask Oracle why they implemented it in this way
My guess is that each standalone subprogram is treated as a database object (you can find them in ALL_OBJECT or USER_OBJECT views, their types are: PROCEDURE and FUNCTION), and each database object must have unique name, so you cannot create two functions or procedures with the same name.